# how to schedule task (whenever schedule.rb) to run on every alternate Saturday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

Attempted schedule task:

```
every '0 1 * * 6#2' do  
    rake 'prj:task1', output: 'log/task1.log'  
end
```

Observing error:

```
gems/whenever-0.10.0/lib/whenever/cron.rb:154:in `parse_as_string': Couldn't parse: 0 1 8-14 (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all take a look at this answer on server fault:

[Same question using only cron job](https://serverfault.com/questions/633264/cronjob-run-every-two-weeks-on-saturday-starting-on-this-saturday)

This should the entry:

```
0 8 * * 6 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 1 && yourCommand
```

The first part is every saturday at 8:00 am, the second you can try this test on console:

```
test $((10#$(date +\%W)%2)) -eq 1 && echo odd || echo even
```

What this code do is get the number of week in a year and get if it is even or odd

if we translate this to ruby

```
every '0 8 * * 6' do
  rake 'prj:task1', output: 'log/task1.log' 
end
```

and in your task add the execution test clause for knowing in which Saturday you are in this case you test the week of the year

```
Time.now.strftime('%W').to_i
 => 15 
Time.now.strftime('%W').to_i % 2
 => 1
```

Then try to apply this with your own needs
So only execute in even or odd weeks of the year

```
if  Time.now.strftime('%W').to_i % 2 == 1
  puts "odd do something" 
else
  puts "even do not do anything"
end
```

I'm not sure if adding the if modifier directly to the whenever shcedule will work

```
every '0 8 * * 6' do
  if  Time.now.strftime('%W').to_i % 2 == 1
    rake 'prj:task1', output: 'log/task1.log' 
  end
end
```

Comment: error:   

    `parse_as_string': Couldn't parse: 0 8 * * 6 test $((10#$(date +\%W)\%2)) -eq 1 (ArgumentError)

Comment: OK I was thinking , that whnever can handle this, I made an update

Answer (score 0):

Another option can be [found here](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2010-January/088261.html)

The final answer might looks like here as:

```
every '30 1 * * 6' do
  (($(date +'%V')&1)) && rake 'prj:task1', output: 'log/task1.log' 
end
```

This basically run every Saturday. But the first check decides whether to run on even/odd weeks.